# Spontaneous Mission Control invocation

Tags: macos, mission-control

I have a very weird situation that when I start my Macbook, Mission Control is invoked many times for a couple of seconds. Then it stops and everything goes back to normal (occasionally though it starts again the craziness but very sporadically).

In the beginning I though that my trackpad was completely broken so I went to System Preferences > Trackpad > More Gestures and I disabled the gesture  there. But unfortunately the problem still persists...

Is there any way to see from where Mission Control takes an invocation command? I thought of adding a keylogger to see if the keyboard is also broken and sends random events but if something else is the problem then this is not enough. I wish there was a debug mode or something that I could see who is talking to which service of my mac :/

Any ideas???

Comment: There's a free app on the App Store called [Key Codes](https://itunes.apple.com/gb/app/key-codes/id414568915?mt=12) which could spot key-presses… but it will spot **all** of them & only whilst running...

Answer (score 2):

I would look at two things:

Check to see if Mission Control is listed in System Preferences -> Desktop & Screen Saver -> Screen Saver -> Hot Corners

Check to see if Mission Control is listed in System Preferences -> Users & Groups -> Login Items

Either of these might cause issues similar to at least some of what was described.

Additionally, when you shut down or log out, if the checkbox "Reopen windows when logging back in" is selected, all the programs that are running when you log out will be restarted the next time you log in - this might be re-launching some software that you don't actually want to use any more. I generally uncheck this box. If you select "Apple Menu" -> "Log Out" and make the checkbox unselected, you can then hit the "Cancel" button to not log out, and the checkbox deselection will be retained.